# Cloning a private repo using HTTPS with gitpython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am using gitpython to clone a git repository over HTTPS. If the project is a private repo, it will prompt for username and password. How do I interact with the prompt pythonically to pass username and password variables ?

```
from git import Repo

HTTPS_REMOTE_URL = 'https://github.com/username/private-project'
DEST_NAME = 'https-cloned-private-project'
cloned_repo = Repo.clone_from(HTTPS_REMOTE_URL, DEST_NAME)
```

Output of running this code:

```
$ python example.py
Username for 'https://github.com': example
Password for 'https://example@github.com':
```

I know it's possible to include the username and password in the URL:

```
HTTPS_REMOTE_URL = 'https://username:password@github.com/username/private-project'
```

However, I have no way of knowing ahead of time if this is a private repo.

Answer (score 12):

it works for me when using github access token instead of username and password where 2FA may be required:

`HTTPS_REMOTE_URL = 'https://<access_token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/username/private-project'`

Comment: This code working with Public Repo Only! and not with the Private one. Error : remote: Repository not found.

Comment: @TusharNiras actually it really works independent on the repo type. If the repo is not yours, you need to receive the invite.

Comment: @ViniciusMesel is right. when github responses `Error : remote: Repository not found`, it's actually a status code `404` means either the repo does not exist (explicit interpretation), or this repo is not accessible by this user (implicit interpretation since GitHub should not tell you if a private repo exist or not).

Comment: I'm facing same problem as @TusharNiras.
I'm able to clone the repo using the same command on my machine but not via my python script.

Comment: Check this: https://teamdynamix.umich.edu/TDClient/47/LSAPortal/KB/ArticleDet?ID=1517