# Connection refused when tried to clone from github Enterprise

Tags: python, git

An error I met when I use git API

```
from git import Repo
from github import Github

Connecting to git.xxxxx.com (port 9418) ... fatal: unable to connect to git.xxxxx.com:
git.xxxxx.com[0: 141.113.0.105]: errno=Connection refused
```

I can clone code from Enterprise github by command

```
git clone https://[name]:[token]@git.git.xxxx.com/xxx.git
```

But I'm confusing the way of clone in git API

```
def walk_githubprojects(token, organization):
    client = Github(base_url='https://git.xxx.com/api/v3', login_or_token=token)
    user=client.get_user().get_repos()
    for repo in client.get_organization(organization).get_repos():
        print(repo.name)
        print(repo.git_url)
        Repo.clone_from(repo.git_url, 'my_path')
```

I can get repo names under organization, the script should clone repos to my local dir

Comment: You might try passing token in git url as it is a private repo and it won't be cloned by just passing git url and path

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358808/cloning-a-private-repo-using-https-with-gitpython/36625960

Comment: I have found the reason,  I got "repo.git_url" that means will be connected in port 9418, the port not opened and the format of remote location should be "https://[name]:[token]@git.git.xxxx.com/xxx"

Answer (score 0):

The solution is：

```
from git import Repo
from github import Github


def walk_githubprojects(token, organization):

    client = Github(base_url='https://git.xxxxx.com/api/v3', login_or_token=token)
    user=client.get_user().get_repos()
    for repo in client.get_organization(organization).get_repos():
        HTTPS_REMOTE_URL = f'https://[name]:[token]@git.xxxxx.com/{repo.full_name}'
        Repo.clone_from(HTTPS_REMOTE_URL, f'/xxxx/{repo.name}')
```